# What good is an F-test and is using it as a test for significance of independent variable worth it?

Tags: r, f-test

An F-test may lead to the conclusion that a predictor is significant by an F-test low p-value. This is because while an independent variable like smoke (below) is statistically unimportant (high p-value), the F-test has a low p-value suggesting its inclusion in the model. Why not remove smoke all together?

Case in point: Smoking is not significant

```
Call:
lm(formula = Height ~ Wr.Hnd + Sex + Smoke, data = survey)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-17.4869  -4.7617   0.7604   4.3691  22.1237 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 137.4056     6.5444  20.996  < 2e-16 ***
Wr.Hnd        1.6042     0.3301   4.860 2.36e-06 ***
SexMale       9.3979     1.2452   7.547 1.51e-12 ***
SmokeNever   -0.0442     2.3135  -0.019    **0.985**    
SmokeOccas    1.5267     2.8694   0.532    **0.595**    
SmokeRegul    0.9211     2.9290   0.314    **0.753**    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.023 on 201 degrees of freedom
  (30 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.5085,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4962 
F-statistic: 41.59 on 5 and 201 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Case in point: F-test shows that combine with sex and writing handspan, smoke's inclusion in the model is acceptable.

```
survmult2 <- lm(Height~Wr.Hnd+Sex+Smoke, data = survey)
R2 <- summary(survmult2)$r.squared
R2

n <- nrow(survey)-30
n

p <- length(coef(survmult2))-1
p

n-p-1

Fstat <- (R2*(n-p-1))/((1-R2)*p)
Fstat
1-pf(Fstat,df1=p,df2=n-p-1)

**[1] 0**  # p-value is way less than <0.05, practically zero
```

Comment: Data is random; there is no guarantee that every true null hypothesis will fail to be rejected, nor that every false null hypothesis will be rejected.  That doesn't mean that the tests are useless, just that they aren't oracles.

Comment: Could you please explain the title and the question in the first line?  I cannot make sense of them.  And could you explain what a "variance equality" test is?

Comment: Variance (variability) equality--null hypothesis: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9pGHRs-cxc

Comment: "Could you please explain the title and the question in the first line?"

If the F-test were to be use to double-check the significance of an independent variable, which already is verifiable with summary() or its use in variance (variability) equality, it decompensates by potentially wrongfully claiming significance or no signifiance for an independent variable. This would seem to throw off its functionality. I'm not understanding why its being used given the wrong assumption it may give, since it makes it that much worse.

Comment: I'm with whuber -- I can't follow the premises and the steps in your title and start of your body text and I still can't follow it in your comment just now. Can you *explain* the situation/reasoning/steps in more detail, please. Imagine you have a smart but ignorant person (someone who has less stats than you) that you're trying to get to understand the problem, so you have to explain in simple but clear terms what you're getting at.

Comment: Looking at survmult2, where two of the predictors yielded small p-values (first gray region above), so then too the omnibus F-test suggests strong evidence against null hypothesis. Although the smoking frequency variable itself doesn't appear to contribute anything statistically important (first gray region above), the F-test for that model still suggest survmult2 should be preffered over a no-predictor model, because both handspan and sex are important.Should F-test be used as a test of model acceptance? I've read it has other components: variance equality & independent variable significance.

Answer (score 1):

The model F-test is an omnibus test that tests the hypothesis that all slopes are jointly equal to zero (or, equivalently, whether the population R2 is zero). If any slope is different from zero in the population, then the null hypothesis is false, and, hopefully, you'll get a significant F-statistic to confirm that. Because it's an omnibus test, it doesn't tell you which slope is different from zero. You have to examine the Wald t-tests for each slope to determine whether each is significantly different from zero. So, the omnibus model F-test and the Wald t-tests for each slope tell you different things. They are not redundant. In your data example, there is evidence that the slopes for `SexMale` and `Wr.Hnd` are different from zero based on the Wald tests. This is consistent with the model F-test which tests whether any slopes are different from zero.

You may ask why you should use the F-test when you can just look at the Wald tests for the slopes and see if any are significant. When you do this, you implicitly perform many comparisons, and the probability of a type I error increases if the slopes are actually zero in the population. The model F-test doesn't suffer from this; it only performs a single comparison, so its type I error rate is nominal (i.e., .05). The recommended course of action is to first examine whether the F-test is significant or not; if not, don't bother looking at the coefficients; if so, look at the coefficient tests to see which ones are significant. This is in general how all omnibus testing proceeds: start with the broadest test, and only probe further if that test indicates significance.

Note that the F-test you manually computed is the same one given by `summary()` at the very bottom, so you didn't need to do that (which I think added confusion). Also I think there is a problem with the clarity of your English that makes it a bit hard to figure out what you're asking and why your explanations are not really helping.